# What is the correct mime-type for serving an iPhone .ipa file?

Tags: iphone, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to post .ipa files onto our apache web server for our beta testers to download. Currently I'm using the following line in .htaccess to serve the files:

```
AddType application/octet-stream .ipa
```

This works great in Safari and Firefox, but in IE the .ipa extension is removed and is instead replaced with .zip.  So instead of MyApp.ipa, IE users will get MyApp.zip.

I know that I could just zip up all the .ipa's before putting them onto the server and then I wouldn't have to deal with any of this, but I'd like to avoid that extra step if there is a more elegant solution server-side.

Or rather, is it possible to simply prevent IE from altering the file extension?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I voted up the other answers as they were both helpful, but this is what I ended up needing to fix the problem.

```
AddType application/octet-stream .ipa
<Files *.ipa>
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</Files>
```

Comment: what about adding .plist support?  Do I just add AddType text/xml .plist or do I need the Files elements all over again?  Also, which file is all of this added in?  Can it go into apache2.conf and apply to everything, or should I put in a virtual host config file?

Comment: I have not tested this with .plist files, but I imagine it should work similar to regular xml. I guess it depends on whether you want the file to download or display in the browser.

Comment: As for where to put the code, either location (vhost or the global apache .conf file) are fine. If you don't want your configuration to take effect globally, put it in the vhost file.

Comment: If you server supports PHP, you may want to take a look at [my php files](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19661276/274502). They're ready for dealing with this.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19661276/902968) has the info about plists. You have to use a specific URL type in your HTML.

Answer (score 6):

A `.ipa` file *is* a zip file:

```
$ file 'Kindle 2.2.1.ipa' 
Kindle 2.2.1.ipa: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract
```

That's likely why IE is helpfully changing the extension for you.  [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775148(VS.85).aspx) seems to indicate that might be the case:

> Internet Explorer sets the file name extension of a downloaded file based on a few pieces of information available from the HTTP server and from the file itself.

Comment: Well, yeah. Creating the .ipa is simply a matter of zipping up the files and changing the extension. Maybe a better way of phrasing the question would be how do I prevent IE from changing my file extension?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you look into [Hockey](http://buzzworks.de/blog/announcing-developer-framework-hockey) which seems like a good way to distribute Ad Hoc updates more seamlessly. php based though.

Comment: Interesting... I'm not entirely opposed to using some PHP to get the job done. A full blown framework probably isn't what I'm after (at least for now) but I'll definitely look it over.

Comment: Plugging again my php files here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19661276/274502 just a couple of them to get the job done! :-P