# iOS Enterprise OTA distribution Unable to Download Application

Tags: ios, enterprise, over-the-air

I created an iOS app and want to distribute it Over-The-Air. I followed this guide:

http://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-apps/mac/1.1/?lang=en-us#app43ad77ea

The App is signed with the enterprise certificate and contains the distribution provisioning profile.

When I try to download the App onto the ipad (using the technique described in this guide), a square icon with my download icon appears on the screen with the name "Waiting...", then a second later the name changes to my actual application name and then again a second later i receive the error message:

> Unable to Download Application
>
> "Your Application" could not be downloaded at this time.

in the guide, there are three troubleshooting tips:

> if wireless app distribution fails with an “unable to download”
>   message, check the following:
>
> Make sure the app is signed correctly. Test it by installing it on a
>   device using iPhone Configuration Utility or Apple Configurator, and
>   see if any errors occur.
>
> Make sure the link to the manifest file is correct and the manifest
>   file is accessible to web users.
>
> Make sure the URL to the .ipa file (in the manifest file) is correct
>   and the .ipa file is accessible to web users.

I checked all three things and they are fine.

What else could cause my download problems?

Comment: Try setting the correct mime-type for .ipa files: "AddType application/octet-stream .ipa" (for Apache server). Check  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728601/what-is-the-correct-mime-type-for-serving-an-iphone-ipa-file

Comment: i had to rebuild - seems the archive (ipa) was missing half the files. no error messages from xcode throught the whole process.

Answer (score 33):

As *alexey* mentioned, too many reasons can cause that message. Apple use it as a "catch all errors".

You can diagnose it through the ***Console***. Connect the device to your desktop and access it either from **XCode's Organizer** (mac only) or **[iPhone Configuration Utility](http://support.apple.com/downloads/#iphone%20configuration%20utility)** (mac and windows). But...

### It just ain't that simple! :-(

*Console* may be far from enough. Sometimes there is *no relevant message* there.

Then, the last resort is [following a ***checklist***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531121/ad-hoc-distribution-for-beta-testing-xcode-4-3). Doing all over from zero again. There are many [out](http://shinydevelopment.com/blog/over-the-air-ios-provisioning-and-distribution/) [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14925205/274502)... But following there's my generic and non-detailed *checklist for Over The Air distribution*, at the moment.

---

---

1. **Have a Distribution build** - This is the most complicated part, done always on the web, and Apple changes the steps all the time. In general, you need a *certificate*, an *identifier* and the *provisioning profile*. Listing devices is *almost* always required. My current choice is "**Distribution -> In House**".

   [image: Apple Developer -> Member Center -> Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles -> Provisioning Profiles -> Add (+)]

   P.S.: If you do want to list the devices, make sure the UDIDs are correct. Many issues reported here.
2. **Set the profile under Project -> Build Settings** - Since XCode 5, things changed. Instead of *code signing* with an *identity* you can clear all that up and set it under *Code Signing -> ***Provisioning Profile**. The Identity should automatically change to "*Automatic*". There's also no more need to manually download files from step 1 and install them. XCode manages that now.

   [image: XCode 5 -> Project Navigator -> Project -> Build Settings]
3. **Archive** - In Xcode 5, there's no need any more to "Build for Archive". Just archive it. It should show up next on **Organizer**, and it will take some time if it's a big project. Many errors can come up on this step, but they're almost always related to code compilation and not to OTA.
4. **Deploy** - Now in *Organizer -> Archives*, select the proper archive (should be already selected as the most recent one) click on "*Distribute*", then **Save for Enterprise or Ad Hoc Deployment**. May be big wait now. When saving the file, there is an option to "*Save for Enterprise Distribution*". That is a completely misleading name. What it really does is create the **plist** file. If you have one already, it's fine. You can even manually edit it, which is generally better. The **plist** be needed for step (5). Here's a good one:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
       <key>items</key>
       <array>
           <dict>
               <key>assets</key>
               <array>
                   <dict>
                       <key>kind</key>
                       <string>software-package</string>
                       <key>url</key>
                       <string>http://example.com/app.ipa</string>
                   </dict>
                   <dict>
                       <key>kind</key>
                       <string>full-size-image</string>
                       <key>needs-shine</key>
                       <false/>
                       <key>url</key>
                       <string>http://example.com/FullSizeImage.png</string>
                   </dict>
                   <dict>
                       <key>kind</key>
                       <string>display-image</string>
                       <key>needs-shine</key>
                       <false/>
                       <key>url</key>
                       <string>http://example.com/Icon.png</string>
                   </dict>
               </array>
               <key>metadata</key>
               <dict>
                   <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                   <string>com.example.app</string>
                   <key>kind</key>
                   <string>software</string>
                   <key>subtitle</key>
                   <string>for iOS</string>
                   <key>title</key>
                   <string>My App</string>
               </dict>
           </dict>
       </array>
   </dict>
   </plist>
   ```
5. **Distribute** - Skip this step if you want to install it using XCode or iPhone Configuration Utility. You're done. This is **putting on the file on a web site**. "Simply" add a HTML page with **a href** link such as this:

   ```
    itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://example.com/app.plist
   ```

   Unfortunately dealing with web servers is never simple. So also [check the server mime-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728601/what-is-the-correct-mime-type-for-serving-an-iphone-ipa-file?lq=1)! I've made a couple PHP files to deal with them, if your server supports php. Just keep your files as they are (the *plist*, *html* and *ipa*) and **link to `app.plist.php`** instead:

   **app.plist.php**

   ```
   $file = fopen("app.plist", "r");
   while(!feof($file)){
       $line = fgets($file);
       print str_replace(".ipa", ".ipa.php", $line);
   }
   fclose($file);
   ?>
   ```

   **app.ipa.php**

   ```
   <?php
   header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');

   $file = fopen("app.ipa", "r");
   while(!feof($file)){
       $line = fgets($file);
       print $line;
   }
   fclose($file);
   ?>
   ```
6. **Verify** - Ensure that all files listed in the assets array are available to download. If any of these files return 404 or such (including the icons) the entire install will fail. You must either (A) make those files available or (B) delete those missing entries from the plist. The icon entries are not required for the download to work.

   Here is an example plist with no icons:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
       <key>items</key>
       <array>
           <dict>
               <key>assets</key>
               <array>
                   <dict>
                       <key>kind</key>
                       <string>software-package</string>
                       <key>url</key>
                       <string>http://example.com/app.ipa</string>
                   </dict>
               </array>
               <key>metadata</key>
               <dict>
                   <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                   <string>com.example.app</string>
                   <key>kind</key>
                   <string>software</string>
                   <key>subtitle</key>
                   <string>for iOS</string>
                   <key>title</key>
                   <string>My App</string>
               </dict>
           </dict>
       </array>
   </dict>
   </plist>
   ```

**The file examples are a very important part of the checklist. They have to be 100% correct.**

## Double check the plist and html files!

<sup>P.S.: I'm writing this answer because, in my case, it was a "simple" matter of wrong link on the *.plist* file. And, as such, it's hard as hell to diagnose. Well, only doing this checklist could I find the error! It was pointing to "another-app.ipa" rather than "app.ipa"!</sup>

Comment: This line helped me get it to work. `                   <string>http://example.com/app.ipa</string>`, make sure `software-package` key points to an actual IPA

Comment: +1 for the console tip. Describes exactly why the app wouldn't install instead of the generic "Unable to install" message that shows up on the device.

Comment: @n00neimp0rtant if that was the reason, give the +1 to [alexey there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17208991/274502). He came up with that! ;-)

Comment: The annoying part about #6 is that there is no information from the console as to why the installation failed. Hope that helps someone from spending the time that I did debugging it!

Comment: @Saltymule I'm sorry mods refused your edit suggestion. I couldn't and won't be able verify it myself, but it looks very useful and accurate. You're right, usually installation errors give way too little to none debugging information.

Comment: I just wanna insist once again on the last point @cregox mentionned. I just lost several hours on a bad path leading to the .ipa ... Triple check guys ;)

Answer (score 12):

There are a plenty of reasons to cause this message.

The best way to diagnose it is to **connect a device to Mac** and look **Console** for the device in **Organizer**.

In my case, for example, it was:

> verify_bundle_metadata: This app was not build to support this device family

Comment: Almost perfect! For more info, please [read my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19661276/274502).

Comment: Updated answer for Xcode 6 and up. **Devices** has been separated from **Organizer**. In Xcode 6 or 7, go into Window > Devices, select the device, and then in the bottom left corner there is a box with an arrow inside of it. Click that and it will expand previously minimized console. 


I found my problem this way, FYI it was incorrect bundle identifier! We changed our bundle name but were reusing the plist file from previous versions and forgot to update it there too.

Comment: It can be hard to find the relevant spot in the console, because it keeps logging, search for the string "Install complete for download" or "Apps Failed be installed"  etc

Answer (score 7):

Answering my own question:

The problem was that one of the thumbnails did not have the correct path set in the manifest.plist - so not only the ipa needs the correct path, but also the temporary download icons, otherwise the installation will fail with the mentioned error message.

Comment: hmm, same problem, but this didn't fix it for me

Comment: @d2burke Setting server MIME types

You may need to configure your web server so that the manifest file and app file are transmitted correctly.

For Mac OS X Server, use Server Admin to add the following MIME types to the MIME Types settings:

application/octet-stream ipa

text/xml plist

For IIS, use IIS Manager to add the MIME type in the Properties page of the server:

.ipa application/octet-stream

.plist text/xml

Comment: This link will be helpful for u and solve ur problem @d2burke http://ios-programming.blogspot.in/2012/04/share-ipa-on-private-server-using-save.html

Comment: This happened to me as well. Followed all of the steps in the accepted answer, but it turns out that one of my thumbnails was a 404.

Answer (score 6):

Another Issue that it could be is that both the .plist **AND** the .ipa need to be hosted with HTTPS and not just regular HTTP. The software package string should look like below:

```
<key>kind</key>
<string>software-package</string>
<key>url</key>
<string>https://example.com/app.ipa</string>
```

Stupid little oversight but it was tripping me up for awhile.

Answer (score 3):

We did experience the very same error message when trying to install an iOS 5+ app to an iOS4.3.5 phone. 
Did you also check deployment/build targets and target architecture to match the device(s) showing that issue?

Comment: I encountered this problem when I switched my Code Signing Identity to Distribution for my TARGET. It was fixed when I switched to Distribution for my PROJECT. I have no idea why these wouldn't be linked.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the casing is matching in all the files. They tend to be case insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was on my device an older version of same app was installed with same bundle identifier (downloaded from applstore) so now when I was trying to download its new version via enterprise distribution it was doing nothing, no error at all. Delete existing version from the device solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found in console.

> installcoordinationd(MobileInstallation)[99] :
>   ****bundleID****:5:11:1:1:Updating PlaceholderMetadata for
>   ****bundleID**** with failure 1 _LSInstallType 1, underlyingError
>   (Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=13 "Failed to verify code
>   signature of
>   /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.IoCSM9/extracted/Payload/App.app
>   : 0xe8008016 (The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.)"
>   UserInfo={LibMISErrorNumber=-402620394,
>   LegacyErrorString=ApplicationVerificationFailed, SourceFileLine=147,
>   FunctionName=+[MICodeSigningVerifier
>   _validateSignatureAndCopyInfoForURL:withOptions:error:], NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to verify code signature of
>   /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.IoCSM9/extracted/Payload/App.app
>   : 0xe8008016 (The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.)}),
>   source 17>

Here we should look at:
**Failed to verify code signature of App.app

The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.**

In my case it was because i downloaded enterprise build from amazon. But the provisioning profile, which it was builded with, was expired (figured out in [developer console](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/)).

---

Another one with the other purpose:

> "This app could not be installed at this time."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=This app could not be installed at
>   this time., NSUnderlyingError=0x100cbd3c0 {Error
>   Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=64 "Upgrade's
>   application-identifier entitlement string (BBBUUUU.com.bundle.www)
>   does not match installed application's application-identifier string
>   (CCCEEEE.com.bundle.www); rejecting upgrade."
>   UserInfo={LegacyErrorString=MismatchedApplicationIdentifierEntitlement,
>   FunctionName=-[MIInstallableBundle
>   _validateApplicationIdentifierForNewBundleSigningInfo:error:], SourceFileLine=878, NSLocalizedDescription=Upgrade's
>   application-identifier entitlement string (BBBUUUU.com.bundle.www)
>   does not match installed application's application-identifier string
>   (CCCEEEE.com.bundle.www); rejected

Here i just removed the previous version of the app. The error was, because i changed the team for the bundle ID and it was installed the app with previous bundle ID.

---

#### Open console with:

- `Xcode` > `Window` > `Devices`
- Select the device
- Expand a console with with a box with an arrow inside of it in the bottom left corner.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking `bundle identifier` in your `XCode` and `.plist` file

Answer (score 0):

In my case I did following to get rid off "cannot connect to dl.dropboxusercontent" message after providing ipa shared link.
1. Removed md5 section from plist
2. Uploaded 512*512 and 57*57 images to drop box, and provided shared link in fill_size_image and display_image in plist.

Comment: Huh? What does dropbox have to do with this?

Comment: The bundle was published on Dropbox,

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check here is that the device you are installing on has the correct OS for the app your are installing.  For instance, if the app is built for iOS 11, and your device has iOS 10 on it, then the app will install but you will see this error "Unable to Download Application".

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was a problem with incorrect file permissions of the FTP folder and the files inside (manifest, ipa, images). Check that they have 775 (rwx) and that Owner/Group is your owner.

The error in the device console was like "**Cannot connect to iTunes Store**" or "**Failed artwork for bundleID**" or "**Failed to load placeholder artwork for bundleID**". But it's just about the files.