# Xcode 9 - iOS 11 Device Log Private

Tags: ios, xcode, logging, installation

I am having problems installing an app I have written via an MDM.

The only error shown on screen is:
"Unable to download app"

Connecting my device to my Mac and looking at the Device Log while installing gives me the following lines:

```
Nov 30 15:08:29 Thomass-iPhone appstored[152] <Error>: !B18:com.MyCompany.MyApp,J:-7184901782002726309,I:5931121481553874548#[<private>]: Failed to install application at path: <private> error: <private>
Nov 30 15:08:29 Thomass-iPhone appstored[152] <Notice>: !B18:com.MyCompany.MyApp,J:-7184901782002726309,I:5931121481553874548#[<private>]: Install failed after error: <private>
```

Is it possible to change the log so that instead of displaying "private", it will display the actual error?

How can I find out why my app won't install?

Comment: I suppose your app is signed by enterprise (inhouse) provision profile. You can try to install your ipa via "Apple Configurator 2" . If you success, that mean your ipa is good. There maybe some problem about your network ( https cert)?

Comment: I can install via XCode no problem. But I'm getting the problem when trying to install via our MDM, MobileIron. However we must use the MDM.

Comment: Have your device installed an earlier version of your app already?

Comment: @KevinCao Yes. I tried upping the version number incase there was a conflict.

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167915/ios-enterprise-ota-distribution-unable-to-download-application I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly but this doesn't seems like logging/debugging question. It's more of an MDM question. Additionally you can ONLY see something private in debug mode and obviously if you install through MDM you are not in debug mode, hence you will NEVER see its value

Answer (score 2):

Build the IPA file with distribution provision profile, and generate a downloadable link from [diawi.com](http://www.diawi.com) . Try downloading from the link. If it works fine then there might be issue with MDM configuration. If not then check the distribution provision profile.